# Jquery datatable - Inline edit columns and save all details on clicking 'save' button

Tags: save, datatables, inline-editing

I am using following `Jquery Datatables` code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url" : '/Book/list/' + book_id,
            "dataSrc": function(data) {
            return data.book_details;
        },
        "searching": false
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id"},
            { "data": "book_name" },
            { "data": "price"},
            { "data": "rank"},
        ]
    });
```

I want to edit the '**Price**' column - Tried editor plugin but since that is not an opensouce plugin, I am not able to use it.

And the second thing i need is :
After editing '**price**' column for every row, by clicking save button, it has to save every modified value in datatable.

Anyone please help?

Comment: I am really stuck with this datatable functions. anyone help please...

Comment: You can render anything you like into the datatable cells, so you can have your own edit buttons, textboxes etc to handle your editing.  Is that what you want?